# URL Root character "~" does not behave consistently in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5. On my local machine I use `http://localhost` but on my server I deploy 
to `http://server/MyApp`

I have the following line in my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<link href="~/lib/jquery-ui/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

which renders without the "~' to

```
 <link href="/lib/jquery-ui/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and then at another place I generate via HTML helper to output

```
@Html.MyCustomHtmlButton(model=>model.Id)

string output="<a href=\""+ "~/area1/folder2/index" +"\">";
output += ".." + "</a>";
return new HtmlString(output.ToString());
```

However this renders to html with the "~"

```
<a href="~/area1/folder1/index" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>Cancel</a>
```

and if you click on it you'll get redirected to

> http://localhost:59693/area1/controller11/edit/~/area1/controller1/index

because of the "~" being rendered in the html.

How do I fix it so that the "~" gets rendered to the correct root so that both `http://localhost`  and `http://server/MyApp` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tildes like that only work when used as plain text in views. By building an `HtmlString` yourself, you're bypass Razor for that URI, so the resolving of the tilde won't work.

Just use `@Url.Action()` to build the URI.

Comment: I need to build the html A tag inside a helper class so I don't have access to Url.Action. I  pass the HtmlHelper so have access to the Html methods but I can't use ActionLink as my A tag surrounds a couple of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ur.Action()` method like following

```
string output="<a href=\""+Url.Action("index", "controller1", new {area="area1"})+"\">";
```

**Update:**

If you are using this in class library then simply use

```
string output="<a href=\""+"/area1/controller1/index"+"\">";
```

Comment: From what I know you cannot reference Url in a class library in ASP.NET 5

Comment: Problem with that answer is that it won't work on my server http://localhost/MyApp. I want something to work on both my dev environment and server

Comment: It not working is why I created my question in the first place

Comment: Your question has `'~'` before the url but my answer hasn't.